# GCM not working on iPad

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrated GCM on my iPhone. It worked really well. After some times I tested same code on iPad . It was surprising for me that on iPad it was unable to work. Even It did not enter in method "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken". When i tested same code again in iPhone it was working well

Comment: That's strange, it should be indistinguishable of the device as long as its on iOS. Does it need additional configuration on the APNs part?  Is the iPad on the same network when testing with the iPhone? You can look into [Setting up a GCM Client for iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) (though I'm assuming you've already done this) to check if it can offer other insights to the issue.

Comment: The only things comes in my mind is that in iPad it is running in 2x Mode. Other things are same. i.e GoogleServicesInfo.plist etc

Comment: I have a new thing. My iPad has version 8.4. I have checked on other iPad which has iOS 9.2. It is working fine on that iPad

Comment: You can look into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906927/dont-receive-push-notifications-with-gcm-on-ios) which seems to have a solution or code snippet for different iOS versions